# От чего отталкиваться при создании калькулятора-головоломки?

Tags: python, разработка-игр, pygame

В чём суть:
Человеку нужно получить некоторое число, имея при этом ограниченный набор кнопок и "ходов" для его получения. В игре бесконечное количество процедурно-генерируемых уровней с нарастающей, до определённого предела, сложностью.
От чего мне отталкиваться? Какие модули использовать? Что изучать? Насколько это вообще сложно?

Comment: Так сколько уровней: бесконечное количество или с нарастающей до определённого предела сложностью, а, значит, и до определённого количества?

Comment: Ограничена сложность, а не количество.

Comment: После того, как ты пройдёшь условные 100 уровней, уровни продолжат генерироваться, но их сложность уже нарастать не будет, и все уровни после сотого будут того же уровня сложности, что сотый